# N permutations of string (with repetitions)

Tags: c, string, permutation

I have to print first n permutations with repetitions of a string.

String is formed with characters 'a','b','c','d','e','f'.

For example, first 10 permutations would be: aaaaaa,aaaaab,aaaaac,aaaaad,aaaaae,aaaaaf,aaaaba,aaaabb,aaaabc,aaaabd.

This is my failed attempt:

```
int main()
{    
  FILE *c;
  c = fopen("C:\\Users\\Korisnik\\Desktop\\tekst\\permutacija.txt", "w");
  char s[6] = "abcdef";
  char t[6] = "aaaaaa";
  s[6] = '\0';
  t[6] = '\0';
  int k = strlen(t);
  int m = k;
  int n;
  scanf("%d", &n);
  int br = 0;
  int i = 0;

  while (br < n) {
    i = 0;

    while (i < 6) {
      t[k-1] = s[i];
      fprintf(c, "%s ", t);
      fprintf(c, "\n");
      i++;
      br++;

      if (br == n) {
        exit(1);
      }
    }

    t[k-1] = 'a';
    k--;

    if (k < 0) {
      k = m;
    }
  }

  return 0;
}
```

And my output for first 10 permutations is:
aaaaa 
aaaaab 
aaaaac 
aaaaad 
aaaaae 
aaaaaf 
aaaa 
aaaaba 
aaaaca 
aaaada

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

(Showing a different idea)If you look carefully you will see that all the permutations are the numbers in base-7. Consider `a` as `0`, `b` as `1` and so on. So for every number `1..n` you will convert it into base `7` and write it (By write it I mean, in place of `0` you put `a`,`1` - `b` etc). That will give you the required result. (Ofcourse in conversion you will have to append `0` to the left of the number as per number of digits you want to show). There are problems in your code:

```
char s[6]="abcdef";
```

is legal in C.

```
s[6]=0;
```

This is not as you are accessing array index out of bound which is Undefined behavior. `strlen(t)` is undefined behavior as `t` is not NUL terminated.

Also you have `fprintf(c,"%s ",t);` in your code - this also leads to undefined behavior, it also expects a `char*` which points to a nul terminated `char` array. This will make your realize that how irrelevant it is to have something like this

```
char s[6]="abcdef";
```

Long story short, use `char s[7]="abcdef";` (same applies to `t` also).